# getting all rows after the smallest value in a column in each group after groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below.
After i do the grouby on 'Cycle' & 'Type', i want to find out the sum/mean/std of only the positive values of the negative values of the rows AFTER the smallest 'Switch' value.
How do i do this?  I think the easier option would be to get a dataframe which has the rows after the smallest switch for all 'Cycle' & 'Type' group.

```html
Cycle Type Time Switch
10 1 101 -0.134
10 1 102 0.001
10 1 103 -0.058
10 1 104 0.035
10 1 105 -0.209
10 1 106 0.002
10 1 107 -0.0443
10 1 108 0.001
10 1 109 -0.368
10 1 110 0.015
10 1 111 -0.009
10 1 112 0.055
10 1 113 -0.014
10 1 114 0.004
10 1 115 -0.033
10 1 116 0.003
10 1 117 -0.0401
10 1 118 0.003
10 1 119 -0.088
10 1 120 0.005
10 1 121 -0.026
10 1 122 0.001
10 1 123 -0.115
10 1 124 0.005
10 1 125 -0.085
10 1 126 0.002
10 1 127 -0.054
10 1 128 0.012
10 1 129 -0.034
8 1 101 -1.876
8 1 102 0.003
8 1 103 -0.134
8 1 104 0.002
8 1 105 -0.036
8 1 106 0.012
8 1 107 -0.08
8 1 108 0.037
8 1 109 -0.027
8 1 110 0.022
8 1 111 -0.001
8 1 112 0.028
8 1 113 -0.009
8 1 114 0.002
8 1 115 -0.006
8 1 116 0.01
8 1 117 -0.002
8 1 118 0.002
8 1 119 -0.002
8 1 120 0.008
8 1 121 -0.011
8 1 122 0.001
8 1 123 -0.028
8 1 124 0.003
8 1 125 -0.063
8 1 126 0.013
8 1 127 -0.003
8 1 128 0.02
8 1 129 -0.113
8 1 130 0.003
8 1 131 -0.03
8 1 132 0.012
8 1 133 -0.078
8 1 134 0.001
8 1 135 -0.764
8 1 136 0.006
8 1 137 -0.268
8 1 138 0.016
8 1 139 -0.171
8 1 140 0.013
8 1 141 -0.286
8 1 142 0.023
```

For the given dataframe, the output would be all the rows below -0.368 for cycle=10 & type=1. On the other hand for cycle=8 & type=1, all rows below -1.876 (so all rows below the first row). 
The output dataframe would be as below (first 9 rows on cycle 10, type 1 are removed & first row of type 8 cycle 1 are removed)

```html
Cycle Type Time Switch
10 1 110 0.015
10 1 111 -0.009
10 1 112 0.055
10 1 113 -0.014
10 1 114 0.004
10 1 115 -0.033
10 1 116 0.003
10 1 117 -0.0401
10 1 118 0.003
10 1 119 -0.088
10 1 120 0.005
10 1 121 -0.026
10 1 122 0.001
10 1 123 -0.115
10 1 124 0.005
10 1 125 -0.085
10 1 126 0.002
10 1 127 -0.054
10 1 128 0.012
10 1 129 -0.034
8 1 102 0.003
8 1 103 -0.134
8 1 104 0.002
8 1 105 -0.036
8 1 106 0.012
8 1 107 -0.08
8 1 108 0.037
8 1 109 -0.027
8 1 110 0.022
8 1 111 -0.001
8 1 112 0.028
8 1 113 -0.009
8 1 114 0.002
8 1 115 -0.006
8 1 116 0.01
8 1 117 -0.002
8 1 118 0.002
8 1 119 -0.002
8 1 120 0.008
8 1 121 -0.011
8 1 122 0.001
8 1 123 -0.028
8 1 124 0.003
8 1 125 -0.063
8 1 126 0.013
8 1 127 -0.003
8 1 128 0.02
8 1 129 -0.113
8 1 130 0.003
8 1 131 -0.03
8 1 132 0.012
8 1 133 -0.078
8 1 134 0.001
8 1 135 -0.764
8 1 136 0.006
8 1 137 -0.268
8 1 138 0.016
8 1 139 -0.171
8 1 140 0.013
8 1 141 -0.286
8 1 142 0.023
```

How do I accomplish this?
In the same way, if i have to get all the rows after the 2nd lowest, how do i do it?
The time keeps increasing, so if we know the time of the lowest 'Switch' all the time values above this 'Time' can be the contents of the new dataframe.

I have the progress as below. 
I was able to find the time of the lowest value with codes below.

```
after_min = switch.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1, 'Switch'))
a = after_min.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Time'].agg('first').reset_index(name='Time')
```

I am not able to create a mask or something like that which would filter the values below the lowest time in each group. Can anyone help?

If there is a way to get all the rows after the lowest value of 'Switch' even when we did not have the 'Time' column, please let me know.

**Update** The answer suggested by WeNYoBen works perfectly if I want to get all the rows after the LOWEST value. However, if i want to get all the rows after the 2nd lowest, it will not work.
With the same logic a mentioned by WeNYoBen, if i can transform the last value in `level=1` of the result of the code below to my group, there may be a possibility to get the rows after 2nd lowest.
 `df.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'Switch'))`
The code above gives the output as seen in the picture below. 63 & 4 are the indexes of 2nd lowest 'Switch' values. If i can only transform these values to each group respectively. Then i can get the rows below the 2nd lowest values using the logic from WeNYoBen (this can also be scaled by changing the nsmallest values in the above code to number desired). I am just not able to transform 63 & 1 to each group. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: what is the smallest value for  10 , 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, i had made the mistake -0.368 was not the lowest value. However, i have corrected that now (made other values smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by using `transform` and `idxmin`

```
df[df.index>df.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).Switch.transform('idxmin')]
```

Comment: wow! that was neat. Is there a way to get to get all the rows after the 2nd lowest/3rd lowest value & so on? I ask because i may have to do it & I think we only have `idxmin` & not `idx2ndmin` or something like that.

Comment: if i use `df.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'Switch'))`, I get the list of 2 lowest values and the index for those values as well and the 2nd lowest is the last value. Is there any way, i can use transform on this?

Comment: @mohanys there is no idx2ndmax ：-（

Comment: i understand, i am asking about using apply to get the index of 2nd lowest value. I have updated the question with what I am thinking. Please have a look. Thanks.